# Rxjs BehaviorSubject<Boolean> is sending last value instead of default "false"

Tags: rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I am using RxJS BehaviorSubject as a singleton instance in my code and this has been my observation so far:

1. On first subscription it sends a default "false" value to the subscriber, which I think is okay and expected.
2. Next when I call next(true) method on it, it sends the correct value (true). This is also expected.
3. Now when a new subscription is made after step-2 , it sends "true" instead of default "false".

This is where I am stuck (at step-3). **I realize BehaviorSubject sends the last value when a new subscription is made but my logic requires me to receive "false" when the subscription is made for the first time not the last value that was sent using next().** How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, BehaviorSubject gets an initial value (and not a default value). For default value, you can use the **startWith** operator:

```js
const someSubject = new Rx.Subject();
const withSomeDefault = someSubject.startWith('some-default');

withSomeDefault.subscribe(console.log);
someSubject.next('some-other-value');
withSomeDefault.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```